# PowerShell get-childitem cannot handle filename starting with [ character even with escape character

Tags: powershell, escaping, character

I have a file in c:\temp directory named as [default].xml.
When I issue command: get-childitem "c:\temp`[default].xml" in the powershell console, it returns me nothing. However if I issue this command: get-childitem "c:\temp*default].xml", it works as expected.

Why escape character on '[' is not working?

Answer (score 6):

See get-help about_wildcards

The [] are wildcard "globbing" operators.  To use get-childitem on files that have those characters, use the -literalpath switch to disable wildcarding of the file spec:

```
get-childitem -literalpath "c:\temp[default].xml"
```

Alternatively, normal wildcarding still works in the .getfiles() method of a directoryinfo object:

```
(get-item c:\).getfiles("temp[default].*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got Microsoft official answer in an old [Technet Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx).

You can use :

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\``[default``].xml'
```